# Visualizing Rubik's Graph

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, group-theory

After the August 2010 discovery that the diameter of [the Rubik graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RubiksGraph.html) is [20](http://www.cube20.com/), I wanted to make a way to visualize Rubik's graph. Since there are about $4.3 \times 10^{19}$ vertices in this graph, it is not feasible to store the whole thing. However, it is a [Cayley graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CayleyGraph.html) of a group with 6 generators, it is 6-[regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph), and given any vertex $v$ in the graph, it's neighborhood $N(v)$ can be generated.

Using [Roman Maeder's Wolfram Demonstrations Project](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RubiksCube/) as a basis, I tried to make a way to visualize this graph, one neighborhood at a time.

Starting with the GraphicsComplex `solved`, and the operation `twist`, which is simple enough to operate:

[image: Rubik's cube, solved state transformed to one front-twist]

I want to construct a graph that displays the neighborhood, namely, those configurations of the Rubik's cube that can be reached by a R,L,F,B,U or D operation. The edge corresponding to the operation above should look like this:

[image: Rubik's cube, first twist]

I would like to do three things:

- Given a configuration $v$, I would like to display $N(v)$, with the edges looking like the graphic above
- Make it interactive, so that when I click on one of the configurations, it's neighborhood is output
- Display the cubes as 3D objects, so that they can be rotated

The 3D part would be nice, but it's not necessary. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am not sure this is what you need.  Please see if it helps.  The little cubes are clickable, but not rotatable.  We could put nicely formatted edge labels as well, but I didn't want to do that now as it would slow it down even more.

```
conf = solved;

Dynamic@Graph[
  Join[
   (conf -> twist[#, conf] &) /@ basic,
   (twist[#, conf] -> conf &) /@ inv /@ basic
   ],

  VertexShapeFunction -> (Inset[
      Button[Graphics3D[#2, Boxed -> False], conf = #2, 
       Appearance -> None], #1, {0.5, 0.5}, #3] &), VertexSize -> 1, 
  EdgeStyle -> Black]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For others than the OP reading this:

You need to download the [source of the demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RubiksCube/), copy everything from the `Initialization :> ( ... )` section of the `Manipulate`, and evaluate it.  The code is very well written and very easy to work with.

Comment: Thanks for adding the bit about the source, I should have added that to the question. Your solution is just what I was looking for!